# I need to use a for-loop to find strings in an array-list that have the same word in them

Tags: c#, for-loop, arraylist

I need to find a way to use a for-loop to find how many strings that are the same word in the same array-list. I need to use the for-loop because everytime it loops and finds another word that is the same I want to add it to an int variable :the following is the code that have tried to use but it didn;t work. variable bedrooms kept saying that it is 0 when it is not

```
foreach (string row in RoomType) // RoomType is the ArrayList
            {

                if (row.Equals("Bedroom"))
                {
                    bedrooms++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can we see some more code?

Answer (score 0):

This code works, which is based on your code.  I am assuming that you are probably doing something in your code where `bedrooms` is getting re-declared during the looping.  This is a guess though.

```
var RoomType = new ArrayList();
var bedrooms = 0;

RoomType.Add("workflow");
RoomType.Add("Bedroom");
RoomType.Add("Bedroom");

foreach (string row in RoomType) // RoomType is the ArrayList
{

    if (row.Equals("Bedroom"))
    {
        bedrooms++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(bedrooms);
```

A different way:

```
var row = RoomType.Cast<string>().ToArray();
var count = row.Aggregate(0, (c, i) => (i.Equals("Bedroom")) ? ++c : c);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not compelled to use a loop, you could try starting with this:

```
int bedrooms = RoomType.ToArray().Count(row => row.Equals("Bedroom"));
```

If you are compelled to use a loop, then please post a bit more of the code so that we can see where and how these objects are being set.